# How can I ensure CassandraOperations.selectOneById() initializes all fields in the POJO?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I'm using Spring Data Cassandra 1.3.4.RELEASE to persist instances of a class that I have. The class is written in Groovy, but I don't think that really matters. I have implemented a CrudRepository, and I'm injecting an instance of CassandraOperations into the repo implementation class. I can insert, delete, and do most of the other operations successfully. However, there's a scenario I'm running into which breaks my test case. My entity class looks something like this:

```
@Table("foo")
class FooData {
  @PrimaryKey("id")
  long id
  @Column("created")
  long updated
  @Column("name")
  String name
  @Column("user_data")
  String userData
  @Column("numbers")
  List numberList = []
}
```

In my test case, I happened to only set a few fields like 'id' and 'updated' before calling CassandraOperations.insert(entity), so most of them were null in the entity instance at the time of insertion. But the numberList field was not null, it was an empty List. Directly after the insert(), I'm calling CassandraOperations.selectOneById(FooData.class, id). I get a FooData instance back, and the fields that were initialized when I saved it are populated with data. However, I was checking content equality in my test, and it failed because the empty list was not returned as an empty list in the POJO coming back from CassandraOperations.selectOneById(). It's actually null. I assume this may be some sort of Cassandra optimization. It seems to happen in the CGLIB code that instantiates the POJO/entity. Is this a known "feature"? Is there some annotation I can mark the 'numberList' field with to indicate that it cannot be null? Any leads are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you file a bug report with a reproducible test case in https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS?

Comment: Hi mp911de. I don't have an account for your Jira server. I created a full Gradle project with a Spock test that shows the bug and tarred it up. The tar file is only 20K, so would you mind if I emailed it to you?

Comment: Or put it to github/a gist

Comment: Here's a Dropbox link where you can find the gzipped tar file. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n68dwae74udaso6/bugCode.tgz?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the test case. Great work. See answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In short

Cassandra stores empty collections as `null` and Spring Data Cassandra overwrites initialized fields.

### Explanation

Cassandra list/set typed columns represent an empty collection as `null`. It does not matter whether the list/set (as viewed from Java/Groovy) was empty or `null`. Storing an empty list yields therefore in `null`. From  here one can't tell whether the state was `null` or empty at the time saving the value.

[image: Insert empty list]

Spring Data Cassandra overwrites *all* fields with values retrieved from the result set and so your pre-initialized fields is set to `null`.
I created a ticket [DATACASS-266](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-266) to track the state of this issue.

### Workaround

Spring Data uses setters if possible so you have a chance to intervene. A very simple `null` guard could be:

`public void setMyList(List<Long> myList) {
    if(myList == null){
          this.myList = new ArrayList<>();
          return;
    }
    this.myList = myList;
  }`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still not 100% sure if this is considered a bug or a feature :-)
I.e. is it the expected behavior, and the answer is to simply make sure all fields are initialized to something useful before persisting the data through the Spring Data repository?

Comment: OK, that makes sense, and it would be what I'd normally do for Java mutators. Unfortunately laziness got in the way. I was writing the entity in Groovy, and Groovy automatically provides accessors/mutators for fields, so I never created the accessor/mutator methods.

Comment: You could argue for both. Spring Data MongoDB does not overwrite pre-initialized properties whose fields do not exist in the Document but on the other hand, MongoDB has no Table-like schema definition but the schema comes from each document.

Comment: I am using 1.5.3 and my setters do not get called by spring data. never hits the breakpoint

Comment: Do you use field or property access?

Comment: @mp911de : I'm trying to achieve the same thing here, but can't get my setter method to hit on the breakpoint.  I've been trying to add `@AccessType(AccessType.Type.FIELD` to the field under my `@Column`, and also to the setter method itself.  But I can't seem to get any breakpoint to hit.

Answer (score 1):

As important addition to mp911de answer you have to set `@org.springframework.data.annotation.AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)` to make this solution work.

Comment: This contribution might be better suited as a comment on mp911de's answer.

Comment: Agree, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation