# Can Cassandra return an empty set/list instead of null

Tags: java, database, cassandra

When writing an object that contains an empty Set or List, Cassandra writes this as null.  Therefore, when querying this object it will create an object with a null Set or List.

Is it possible to get Cassandra to create an empty Set/List instead of null, or to not write the null in the first  place?

Comment: This SO answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349896/how-can-i-ensure-cassandraoperations-selectonebyid-initializes-all-fields-in-t

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is more or less a columnar database, so its null is not a null as in SQL. In Cassandra's null means that this column in this row does not exist at all in database and does not occupy any space.

I think your language's Cassandra client API just checks that Set/List is empty and excludes it from the INSERT/UPDATE to optimise the query.

So, this is by design, you should just keep this in mind when interacting with Cassandra.