# Updating to empty set

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I just created a new column for my table

```
alter table user add (questions set<timeuuid>);
```

Now the table looks like

```
user (
    google_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    date_of_birth timestamp,
    display_name text,
    joined timestamp,
    last_seen timestamp,
    points int,
    questions set<timeuuid>
)
```

Then I tried to update all those null values to empty sets, by doing

```
update user set questions = {} where google_id = ?;
```

for each google id.

However they are still null.

How can I fill that column with empty sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learnt that there's not really such a thing as an empty set, or list, etc.

These display as `null` in `cqlsh`.

However, you can still add elements to them, e.g.

```
> select * from id_set;
 set_id                | set_content
-----------------------+---------------------------------
 104649882895086167215 | null
 105781005288147046623 | null

> update id_set set set_content = set_content + {'apple','orange'} where set_id = '105781005288147046623';
 set_id                | set_content
-----------------------+---------------------------------
 104649882895086167215 | null
 105781005288147046623 | { 'apple', 'orange' }
```

So even though it displays as `null` you can think of it as already containing the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

> A set, list, or map needs to have at least one element because an
>   empty set, list, or map is stored as a null set.

[source](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertSet.html)

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349896/how-can-i-ensure-cassandraoperations-selectonebyid-initializes-all-fields-in-t) might be helpful if you're using a client (java for instance).