# convert null values corresponding to an Array to empty array in nifi jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to achieve following JSON transformation using Jolt processor in NIFI
By focusing on values field, in the first input in json (id 900551), values are populated as the following

input JSON

```
{
    "id": 900551,
    "internal_name": [],
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 1430156,
            "form_field_id": 900551,
            "pos": 0,
            "weight": null,
            "category": null,
            "created_at": "2020-10-15 12:55:02",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-27 10:45:09",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "settings": {
                "image": "myimage.png"
                "fix": false,
                "bold": false,
                "exclusive": false
            },
            "internal_value": "494699DV7271000,6343060SX0W1000,619740BWR0W1000",
            "css_class": null,
            "value": "DIFFERENCE",
            "settings_lang": {},
            "value_html": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

On the second input Json file to parse, values is null.

```
{
    "id": 900552,
    "internal_name": [],
    "values": []
}
```

I would like to convert null values to an empty array in my conversion

Is there a way to do this using existing Jolt operations ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`default` operation](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Defaultr.java#L33) is what you are looking for:

> Defaultr walks the spec and asks "Does this exist in the data?  If not, add it."

In our case:

> if the value for `"values"` key is `null`, put the empty array instead

Here is the spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "values": []
    }
  }
]
```

tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

---

**edit:** answering the question from the comment:

Maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36396627/4880379) will work for you

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my Json, I have [], and I want to store this data in Cassandra, but I have null instead of empty Array. Do you have an idea about how to store empty Array instead of null in Cassandra (sorry I know it is not related to jolt)